# What is the comma (,) in the middle of print used for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering what the comma in the middle of `print` is used for?

This code:

```
print('No. of lower case letters : ', d['lower'])
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, `print` is not a statement (it was in Python 2.7). Also, 70% of your code is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A bit of history

Since Python 3, there is actually no print statement. Print is a function just like any other (In the now obsolete Python 2, `print` was indeed actually a statement).

A special case in Python 2 is that you could indeed have a comma at the end, such like

```
print "my string",
```

This would print the string with a space rather than a line feed as the terminator, allowing multiple print statements to contribute to one line. But forget about all this now, Python 2 is long gone (well, since January 2020).

#### Now to your question.

All functions in Python accept a number of arguments separated by a comma. The print function is no different. The print function takes any number of positional arguments, as well as a number of well-known named arguments, e.g.

```
print(a,b,c, file=f)
```

will send the positional arguments `a`, `b` and `c` and the keyword argument `file`. The print function will **concatenate** all positional arguments (separated by space) when printing them (optionally to the file specified by the `file` argument, otherwise to standard output).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback :) . Also, thank you for pointing out that `print` was not a statement. It was a mistake on my part and have edited it out.

Comment: @Naffazz your edit made this answer a bit irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The comma let's you add multiple arguments to the print statement. It basically lets you print them in succession, separated by a space.

Example:

```py
print('hi', 'hello', 'greetings')
#hi hello greetings
```

Answer (score 3):

The comma will let you print multiple strings in one calling of the [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). By default, each string will be separated by a space.

These are the arguments for the print function:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```

You can change the `sep` argument to something else.

Comment: I don't see any comma at the end in the OP's example code.