# Python Beginner Question on comma Behaviour

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote the following program:

```
print ("Mom the food was good:"),
print ("Yummy"* 3)
```

Based on  Python Programming Micheal Dawson
the expected result is,

```
Mom the food was good:YummyYummyYummy

where as the result I get is :

Mom the food was good:

YummyYummyYummy
```

Why isn't the comma between the 2 prints not suppressing the newsline?

Comment: The comma should be _inside_ the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) call. See [What is the comma (,) in the middle of print used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62540915/2745495)

Comment: I think you are using materials that were written for Python 2. In Python 3, `print` is no longer a statement, but a function, and the commas won't work this way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure you understand, and then explicitly clarify, what version of Python you expect the book to be written for, and what version of Python you expect that you are using to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't the comma between the 2 prints not suppressing the newsline?

Because that was a feature of the Python 2 *print statement*. Python 3 (which you *should* be learning) no longer has a print statement, `print` is a function, and the commas cannot act like this. Essentially,

```
print(something),
```

is a *tuple literal*, evaluating to `(None,)`

In Python 3, the `print` function accepts `sep=' '` and  `end='\n'` keyword arguments (the defaults shown), which can be used to control this behavior:

```
print("Hello ", end="")
print("World")
```

Or:

```
print("everything", "on", "it's", "own", "line", sep="\n")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you might show him what the Python 3 method of doing this is.

Answer (score 0):

print has '\n' in the end,you can use print("hello",end="")

Answer (score 0):

The comma between the operators "print" does not concatenate them.
To write code that prints a message in one line, you need to use optional operator ["end"](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print)

```
    print ("Mom the food was good:", end='')
    print ("Yummy" * 3)
```

Output:

```
    Mom the food was good:YummyYummyYummy
```